# Unable to sign an IPA with IDEA and RoboVM

Tags: ios, intellij-idea, libgdx, certificate, robovm

I hope you can help me with this conundrum because I've been trying to fix this for several days with no success.

I want to update my game on iOS, so I got the new provisioning profile and p12 certificate for the game from the publisher and I installed them on my machine. I also have the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority certificate installed (to be expired on February 7th 2023).

My problem is that the when I try to create the IPA file (in IDEA, RoboVM -> Create IPA) no Signing Identity is listed, so I can not create the IPA file. If I go to the keychain it seems the certificate is properly installed. No other version, expired or non-expired, is listed. However, that certificate is listed as non-trusted. Then, what I already tried is to set that non-trusted certificate to "Always trust". Then it appears in IDEA and I can ¿successsfully? create an IPA file. Then the problem comes when I submit it through the Application Loader, because then I get an error message:

> ERROR ITMS-90034: "Missing or invalid signature. The bundle 'A.B.C' at bundle path 'Payload/D.app' is not signed using an Apple submission certificate.

In case it helps, I'm using the same environment I used to create the previous IPA file for our game: IDEA 2018.2.3 Community Edition, RoboVM 2.3.5 and libGDX 1.9.8. I just updated the provisioning profile and signing certificate as the previous ones had expired.

After looking for solutions for this issue, I've already tried removing and reinstalling certificates, restarting XCode and the machine, changing "trust mode" of the certificate... I don't know what else to try, and as some of you may have faced this issue before or may have a clue about what might be happening, I'd love to hear your suggestions.

Any clue on this would be really appreciated so, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

2.3.5 is quite old version. and it doesn't support `Apple Development` kind of identity (and will not show it in the list).
Upgrading it to recent 2.3.12 probably will fix the issue

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't support Apple Development"? As I said, the first version of the game was released using those IDE versions. The only thing that has changed are Apple certificate and provisioning profile.

Comment: sorry misread that it can see signing identity after you changed `trust` value. 
other similar posts tells that trust mode should be `Use System Defaults` not `Always trust`. same to be set for `Apple Worldwide Developer Certification Authority` (also recent one from apple valid till 2030)

Comment: As mentioned in the OP, if trust mode is set to "Use System Defaults" then it is not listed in IDEA. That's my issue, basically.